# Can an elf apparate in the Room of requirement

Tags: harry-potter

Can a house elf apparate in the Room of requirement from Hogwarts or not?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm guessing because "There's no mention of this in whole of the HP". If there's no mention then I would guess there's no canon answer...

Comment: I mean books,..but I may be wrong

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't downvote but I thought you meant you already know there's no answer to it at all!

Comment: Alternatively, the fact that it’s so similar to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/limits-of-elf-apparition may have prompted a down vote.

Comment: @alexwlchan - an appropriate response to a duplicate question is a VTC as dupe; **not** a downvote. And all 3 VTCs were as totally invalid "Primarily opinion based" mis-reason.

Comment: @DVK: I didn't downvote; I was just guessing why people might have done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All signs point towards the answer being no.

> The door of the Room of Requirement opened, and closed. Harry looked round to see who had entered, but there did not seem to be anybody there. It was a few moments before he realized that the people close to the door had fallen silent. Next thing he knew, something was tugging at his robes somewhere near the knee. He looked down and saw, to his very great astonishment, Dobby the house-elf peering up at him from beneath his usual eight woolly hats.
>   
>   <sub>Order of the Phoenix, Chapter Twenty-Seven - *The Centaur and the Sneak*</sub>

If Dobby was capable of Apparating directly into the Room of Requirement then I see no reason he wouldn't have done so rather than entering through the door.

Comment: if Dobby didn't apparate,it doesn't imply he can't, would house elves have to apparate everywhere to prove they can apparate there?

Comment: @TomLynd I (obviously) disagree. The fact Dobby didn't apparate to the Room of Requirement doesn't definitively prove that he can't do so, but I think it strongly implies that he can't. He was in a hurry to warn Harry and had a very limited amount of time to do so, why would he not apparate there in those circumstances if he was capable of doing so?

Comment: As for the second half: yes, absolutely. That's the only means we have, other than JKR choosing to answer the question for us, of proving anything. If they aren't shown to be able to do it in canon then the best we can do is speculate.